# Do not print anything when calling names() in R

Tags: r, names

The function is as below.

```
fun1 = function(x){
  y = 1
  cat(x)
  cat("\n")
  result = list(x = x, y = y)
  invisible(result)
}
```

When I call names()

```
names(fun1(2))
```

I get

```
2
[1] "x" "y"
```

I do not want to see `2` to be printed out when using function `names`. However, I expect `2` to be printed out when calling `fun1(2)`. How can I modify my codes? Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: would calling them out separately work ? `out <- fun1(2)` and then `names(out)` ?

Comment: You might be able to ***infer*** that `fun1` is being called within `names` (or anything, really) by using `sys.nframe()` (0 when in global, 1 or more inside another call), but that is inconsistent when you call `fun1(2)` from within another function and not have it encapsulated in `names`. Perhaps you can add an argument `fun1 <- function(x, verbose=TRUE) {...}` and be explicit/clear about your intentions and expectations?

Comment: But it is more convenient for user to use ```names(fun1(2))``` directly....I am developing a package.